# bash script split array of strings to designed output

Tags: arrays, string, bash

Data in log file is something like:

```
"ipHostNumber: 127.0.0.1
ipHostNumber: 127.0.0.2
ipHostNumber: 127.0.0.3"
```

that's my code snippet:

```
readarray -t iparray < "$destlog"
unset iparray[0]

for ip in "${iparray[@]}"
do
   IFS=$'\n' read -r -a iparraychanged <<< "${iparray[@]}"
done
```

And what I wanted to receive is to transfer IP's to another array and then read every line from that array and ping it.

UPDATE: I've acknowledged something, it's probably that I want one array to another but without some string, in this case cut "ipHostNumber: " and have remained only IPs.

Thanks in advance, if there's anything missing please let me know.

Comment: `what I wanted ... ping it.` Then do you need arrays at all? Just ping them.

Comment: Okay, though I have to cut somehow the string before IP

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need arrays at all? Just read the input and do the work.

```
while IFS=' ' read -r _ ip; do
   ping -c1 "$ip"
done < "$destlog"
```

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .

Another way is to use xargs and filtering:

```
awk '{print $2}' "$destlog" | xargs -P0 -n1 ping -c1
```

Comment: Well, the first solution works pretty well, thank you, I don't know much from bash. Is there a way to always cut/ignore first line while reading from file?

Comment: `awk 'NR > 1' ...`

Comment: Yes, I've seen awk 'NR > 1' and sed 1d, though I see it's not working in this case with while loop or it's wrongly used: 

_sed 1d | while IFS=' ' read -r _ ip
do
   echo "$ip"
done < "$destlog"_

Comment: @blazzeq use `< <(tail -n+2 "$destlog")` instead of `< "$destlog"`

Comment: @blazzeq take a look at [What to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Jetchisel one more thing, when I used script on my environment it worked with "done < <(tail -n+2 "$destlog")" but when I moved to prod environment I have this error code:
_script.sh: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
script.sh: line 30: `done < <(tail -n+2 "$destlog")'_

Comment: @blazzeq, the `< <( ... )` is not `POSIX sh` but `bash` so use `bash`.

Comment: `sed 1d | while IFS=' ' read -r _ ip do echo "$ip" done < "$destlog" ` input `destlog` to sed not to while. Please read the bashfaq/001 link and also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 . Do `sed .. "$destlog" | while ...` or `{ sed ... | while ... done; } < "$destlog"`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer KamilCuk's `xargs` solution, but if you just wanted the array because you plan to reuse it -

```
$: readarray -t ip < <( sed '1d; s/^.* //' file )
```

Now it's loaded.

```
$: declare -p ip
declare -a ip=([0]="127.0.0.2" [1]="127.0.0.3")
$: for addr in "${ip[@]}"; do ping -c 1 "$addr"; done
```